# Azure ARM template validation in DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am looking for a way to define Azure ARM template validation in DevOps based on my company's recommendations.

In this particular case, what we want to enforce is that

- httpsOnly must be set to "true" if it is set
- minTlsVersion must be set to "1.2" if it is set
- ftpsState: must be set to "FtpsOnly" if defined.

Therefore, all builds that do not meet these requirements must fail.
Please, how can I acquire this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - while you indeed can enforce such validation in CICD pipelines, it's much better to use things like Azure Policy and enforce those centrally. Nonetheless, if you are using ARM Templates, there's a project called `arm-ttk` - https://github.com/Azure/arm-ttk. It's specifically designed for testing & validating templates.

You can check examples here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-test-cases - and decide for yourself whether it fulfills your requirements.